# how to set static ip for guest OS on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, oracle-database, oracle-linux

My host is Ubuntu 12.04 and I have installed Virtual Box on it. Network setting of Virtual Box is NAT.

Then I have Oracle Enterprise Linux as guest.

Now I want to set a static IP for my guest, because it's one of pre-requisites of oracle installation.

I tried setting static IP using "Applications menu -> System Settings -> Network" but oracle installer complains about dhcp IP again.

Any helps are appreciated.
My Linux knowledge is so limited.

P.S: In /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 I have

```
BOOTPROTO=none
```

Since I'm using Virtual Box I guess this is different from other questions about static/dhcp ip.

Comment: Your guessing wrong, setting a static IP address in a Linux VM is not different from setting it on Linux on bare metal. I would always use DHCP to hand out static IP address based on the (VM's) MAC address. But Oracle is probably to dumb to recognise that and allow central administration of such your IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

As stated here:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/linux-network-configuration

You should edit the file: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
and then put something like the following:

```
IPADDR=192.168.0.100
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
```

Of course with the IP address, mask, gw and your DNS data.
After that file is modified you may need to bring down/up your interface to apply those settings. Probably you will have to do this using the user 'root':

```
ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0
```

Check if these have been applied correctly:

```
ifconfig eth0
```

Also keep in mind that the VirtualBox NAT network applies by default a DHCP Server, so you may want to change the interface of your guest VM to "bridge" rather than NAT. More info about this on: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat

In the  first link above there is more advance information about configuring the interfaces in case you need it.

Comment: I did as above, but oracle installer says network configuration check is not executed and recommends to use static IP (exactly the same message as before new config) . Should I ignore it?